# How to add numbers inside 2D arrays

Tags: java

So I want to add the rows and columns in this 2D array right here.
The array looks like this:

```
int[][] array = new int[3][3];
    array[0][0] = 0;
    array[1][0] = 0;
    array[2][0] = 0;
    array[1][0] = 0;
    array[1][1] = 1;
    array[1][2] = 2;
    array[2][0] = 0;
    array[2][1] = 2;
    array[2][2] = 4;
```

So I have this set up in a 3x3 matrix on a sheet of paper and the first row should print out 0, second row should print out 3, third row should print out 6
first column should print out 0, second column should print out 3, third column should print out 6. 
I have no clue where to start and I just need to see how to do this problem, because I have a few questions after this that involve this, so if you can just give me code that I can read it would be really helpful! Thanks!

Comment: *so if you can just give me code that we can read it would be really helpful!* This is supposed to come from you

Comment: I don't know where to start! All I have is the 2D array and I need to add rows separately and the columns separately.

Comment: have you try for loop?

Comment: @asdfasf I rolled back your edit since it entirely changes the content of the question and invalidates all existing answers. If you have a follow-up question, please use the "Ask Question" button to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create two for loops - outer one goes through the rows, inner one goes through the columns. Then sum up the values for every column of a given row.

```
int[] colSums = {0,0,0};

for (int c=0;c<array.length;c++) {
    int rowSum = 0;
    for (int c2=0;c2<array[c].length;c2++) {
        rowSum += array[c][c2];
        colSums[c2] += array[c][c2];
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of row "+c+": "+rowSum);
}

for (int c=0;c<colSums.length;c++) {
    System.out.println("Sum of column "+c+": "+colSums[c]);
}
```

Comment: I just noticed though, it doesn't work for the columns?

Comment: Updated to includes column sums